# What is this Typescript `0` type?

Tags: typescript

Why does this code throw a Typescript error?

```
const foo: number | undefined = 22

function bar(x: Date | undefined) {
    !!x && console.log(x) || console.log('x is undefined')
}

bar(foo && new Date())
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TS2345: Argument of type '0 | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date | undefined'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date'
```

Seems like there are two cases:

1. `foo` is a `number` → `foo && new Date()` is of type `Date`
2. `foo` is `undefined` → `foo && new Date()` is of type `undefined`

Where does the `0` type come from here?

Answer (score 3):

The only case where `foo && new Date()` is `false` is when foo is `0`. `0` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value so [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) will return the first falsy value that makes the condition false which is `0`.

If foo was any number apart from zero it would be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and the `Date` object, the last truthy value would instead be returned.

This means `foo && new Date` can be only ever either `0`, a `Date` or `undefined` whereas your function is typed only for a `Date` or `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Makes sense. Is there a fix for this that's less clunky than `foo == undefined ? undefined : new Date()`?

Answer (score 1):

So there is a case when foo is falsy. Since it is a number, only `falsy` value possible is 0.

Here is a quote from the `&&` docs:

> More generally, the operator returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all truthy.

That's why the below two statements return 0.

```js
console.log(0 && 1);
console.log(0 && new Date());
```

The reason you do not get any error with regards to `undefined` is because [`undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#:%7E:text=TypeScript%20has%20two%20special%20types,valid%20values%20of%20every%20type.) type is assignable to anything.